# How to detect, that drawing a canvas object is finished?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have following JS code (found here, on stackoverflow, and a little-bit modded), which resize image on client side using *canvas*.

```
function FileListItem(a) {
    // Necesary to proper-work of CatchFile function (especially image-resizing).
    // Code by Jimmy Wärting (https://github.com/jimmywarting)
    a = [].slice.call(Array.isArray(a) ? a : arguments)
    for (var c, b = c = a.length, d = !0; b-- && d;) d = a[b] instanceof File
    if (!d) throw new TypeError('expected argument to FileList is File or array of File objects')
    for (b = (new ClipboardEvent('')).clipboardData || new DataTransfer; c--;) b.items.add(a[c])
    return b.files
}

function CatchFile(obj) {
    // Based on ResizeImage function.
    // Original code by Jimmy Wärting (https://github.com/jimmywarting)

    var file = obj.files[0];
    // Check that file is image (regex)
    var imageReg = /[\/.](gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png|bmp)$/i;
    if (!file) return

    var uploadButtonsDiv = document.getElementById('upload_buttons_area');
    // Check, that it is first uploaded file, or not
    // If first, draw a div for showing status
    var uploadStatusDiv = document.getElementById('upload_status_area');

    if (!uploadStatusDiv) {
        var uploadStatusDiv = document.createElement('div');
        uploadStatusDiv.setAttribute('class', 'upload-status-area');
        uploadStatusDiv.setAttribute('id', 'upload_status_area');
        uploadButtonsDiv.parentNode.insertBefore(uploadStatusDiv, uploadButtonsDiv.nextSibling);
        // Draw sub-div for each input field
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          var uploadStatus = document.createElement('div');
          uploadStatus.setAttribute('class', 'upload-status');
          uploadStatus.setAttribute('id', ('upload_status_id_commentfile_set-' + i + '-file'));
          uploadStatusDiv.append(uploadStatus);
        }
    }

    var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('canvas-area');
    var currField = document.getElementById(obj.id);
    var currFieldLabel = document.getElementById(('label_' + obj.id));

    // Main image-converting procedure
    if (imageReg.test(file.name)) {
        file.image().then(img => {
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
            canvas.setAttribute('id', ('canvas_' + obj.id));
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
            const maxWidth = 1600
            const maxHeight = 1200

            // Calculate new size
            const ratio = Math.min(maxWidth / img.width, maxHeight / img.height)
            const width = img.width * ratio + .5|0
            const height = img.height * ratio + .5|0

            // Resize the canvas to the new dimensions
            canvas.width = width
            canvas.height = height

            // Drawing canvas-object is necessary to proper-work
            // on mobile browsers.
            // In this case, canvas is inserted to hidden div (display: none)
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height)
            canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas)

            // Get the binary (aka blob)
            canvas.toBlob(blob => {
                const resizedFile = new File([blob], file.name, file)
                const fileList = new FileListItem(resizedFile)

                // Temporary remove event listener since
                // assigning a new filelist to the input
                // will trigger a new change event...
                obj.onchange = null
                obj.files = fileList
                obj.onchange = CatchFile
            }, 'image/jpeg', 0.70)
        }
        )

        // If file is image, during conversion show status
        function ShowConvertConfirmation() {
            if (document.getElementById('canvas_' + obj.id)) {
                document.getElementById(('upload_status_' + obj.id)).innerHTML =
                '<font color="#4CAF50">Konwertowanie pliku ' + file.name + ' zakończone!</font>';
                return true;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById(('upload_status_' + obj.id)).innerHTML =
                '<font color="#4CAF50">Konwertowanie pliku ' + file.name + ' zakończone!</font>';
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Loop ShowConvertConfirmation function untill return true (file is converted)
        var convertConfirmationLoop = setInterval(function() {
            var isConfirmed = ShowConvertConfirmation();
            if (!isConfirmed) {
                ShowConvertConfirmation();
            }
            else {
                // Break loop
                clearInterval(convertConfirmationLoop);
            }
        }, 2000); // Check every 2000ms
        }
    // If file is not an image, show status with filename
    else {
        document.getElementById(('upload_status_' + obj.id)).innerHTML =
        '<font color="#4CAF50">Dodano plik ' + file.name + '</font>';
        //uploadStatusDiv.append(uploadStatus);
    }
}
```

Canvas is drawn in hidden div:

```
<div id="canvas-area" style="overflow: hidden; height: 0;"></div>
```

I am only detect, that div *canvas-area* is presented and basing on this, JS append another div with status.

Unfortunatelly on some mobile devices (mid-range smartphones), message will be showed before finish of drawing (it is wrong). Due to this, some uploaded images are corrupted or stay in original size.

How to prevent this?

Comment: Everything that should happen after the image has loaded should be within the `then` callback (or called from within it).

Comment: @trincot thank you. After some days of tests I can confirm that works good!

Comment: Posted as answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that should happen after the image has loaded, should be executed within the `then` callback, or called from within it.

It is important to realise that the code that is *not* within that callback will execute immediately, well before the drawing has completed.